# what Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) do?

Tags: android, sdk, kill-process

I'm developing android SDK for many apps to use it. In this SDK I use this line of code `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`. In one of my activities and it removes all the background processes and saved data in application class but I handled it in the SDK, but does this line of code affect in the applications that uses this SDK? Will it gives the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` will kill all the process including all the activities on the stack that you started. killProcess will not return to the previous activity. It will kill all the activities started in this process.

If you don't want to kill all the activities started then adopt the following code,

```
Intent i=new Intent(mainclass.this,nextclass.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: ok if it's only exist in the sdk will it affect also in the application that uses the sdk?

Comment: is there anyway else to kill just process happen in one activity without affecting the rest of the app

Comment: yes...Use finish(); instead of Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());. Read my updated answer.

Comment: i use finish() but it doesn't work for me as the background threads comes from JNI code